# Android - How to set listener for videoView when video is completely downloaded

Tags: android, android-videoview

i've a video view in my application ,I've set visibility to gone and I want to change the visibility to visible when the video is completely downloaded .

I tried to use setOnPreparedListener , it works fine when the videoView visibility is visible and it will call when the video is fully loaded but If the videoView visibility is Gone , this listener is not calling at all , I don't know why .

```
final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vide);
        videoView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(1,1));
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(video);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.requestFocus();


        try {
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("this", e.getMessage());
        }

        videoView.requestFocus();

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                Log.v("this", "video");
            }
        });
```

How can I notify when the video is downloaded and change videoView visibility to visible after that ?

Comment: did you test **invisible** ?

Comment: you can also put empty **View** with black background and when is prepare change visibility of that **View**

Comment: @Amir I've tried it before but somewho it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

There are two suggested option which I mentioned as comment But in my opinion the best way is to use [exoMedia](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia) library.

It's gives you ability to set **preview** image when your Video is not ready with following piece of code:

```
emVideo.setPreviewImage(YOUR_URI)
```